# Replace a string in a file, and have some feedback about what was done

Tags: powershell, replace, powershell-2.0

I would like to replace a string in a file, and then know if something was actually replaced.
I have many files to parse, and I know only very few will have to be corrected.
So I would like to write the file out only if a changed occurs. Also I would like to be able to trace the changes in a log...

For example, I've been trying this :

```
(Get-Content $item.Fullname) | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace $old, $new} |
  Out-File $item.Fullname
```

But using I can't tell if any changes were done or not...

Do you have any solution?

Answer (score 2):

Do it in multiple steps:

```
$content = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($item.FullName)
$changedContent = $content -replace $old,$new

if ($content -ne $changedContent) {
    # A change was made
    # log here
    $changedContent | Set-Content $item.FullName
} else {
    # No change
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. Though, I tried your code and it always says "A change was made" but the content of the file doesn't change, only the timestamp does.
And the -Raw is not reconized, I get an error using this parameter.
`+         $content = Get-Content $item.FullName -Raw <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Content], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand`

Comment: Another problem is that the output file is twice bigger, seems to be unicode though the input file is ANSI !

Comment: @Encore I've updated the answer. The `-Raw` parameter requires v3+, so I used a different method to read all the text at once. With that solved you shouldn't be getting changes every time anymore. The changed file is Unicode because `Out-File` defaults to Unicode. I've changed it to `Set-Content` which defaults to ASCII. You could also use `Out-File -Encoding Ascii` for that.

Answer (score 1):

Use `select-string` like `grep` to detect the string and log a message, then use `get- and set-content` to replace the string:

```
$item = 'myfile.txt'
$searchstr = "searchstring"
$replacestr = "replacestring"

if (select-string -path $item -pattern $searchstr) {
    write-output "found a match for: $searchstr in file: $item"
    $oldtext = get-content $item
    $newtext = $oldtext.replace($searchstr, $replacestr)
    set-content -path $item -value $newtext
}
```

Comment: It says System.Object[] doesn't have a replace method. So I added a [String] cast to $oldtext.replace. Now my output file is empty... null size !

Comment: @Encore what version of powershell are you using?

Comment: @Encore if you're using V2, then you should use `$newtext = $oldtext -replace $searchstr, $replacestr`

Comment: @Encore hmmmm... don't know what to say.  Works perfectly on my system (V3).  Is there something special about the encoding you're using, maybe?

Comment: After correcting my mistakes(the [string] cast was removing the carriage returns], it works ! Right file size(means right encoding), your code seems to do the job !
I just have one CR in excess in the new file. I can live with that I guess...
Thank you very much ! (I will still search why I have an additionnal CR though :P)